# InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect, .net-5

I'm new to IdS4. In my case I have and IdS4 and a Web App using Authorization Code for an interactive authentication method usin *Opend Id Connect*. Everything works fine locally. The problem is when I publish de IdS4 in a Linux server:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleChallengeAsyncInternal(AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I can reach Ids4 urls perfectly using web browser:

https://pruebasids.xxxxx.com/ and
https://pruebasids.xxxxx.com/.well-known/openid-configuration/

If I try to use
https://pruebasids.xxxxx.com/connect/token to get a token using Client Credentials it works fine.

Here is my code:

Ids Client Configuration:

```
new Client {
                    ClientId = "myWebapp",
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret( "myPassword.Sha256( ) ) },

                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

                    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5444/signin-oidc" },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5444/home/index" },

                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "myApi.read", "myApi.write", "role" },
                    RequirePkce = true,
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    AllowPlainTextPkce = false
                },
```

Ids4 Startup Configuration

```
public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services ) {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>( options =>
                options.UseSqlServer( Configuration.GetConnectionString( "myDB" ) )
            );

            services.AddIdentityServer( )
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential( )
                .AddInMemoryApiResources( Config.ApiResources )
                .AddInMemoryClients( Config.Clients )
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources( Config.IdentityResources )
                .AddInMemoryApiScopes( Config.ApiScopes )
                .AddProfileService<ProfileService>( );

            services.AddControllersWithViews( );
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure( IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env ) {
            if ( env.IsDevelopment( ) ) {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage( );
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection( );
            app.UseStaticFiles( );
            app.UseRouting( );

            app.UseIdentityServer( );
            app.UseAuthorization( );


            app.UseEndpoints( endpoints => endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute( ) );
        }
```

And finally, my Web App startup configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);

            services.AddHttpClient();

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookie";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
                .AddCookie("Cookie", options =>
                {
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/home/accessdenied";
                })
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "https://pruebasids.xxxxx.com";
                    options.MetadataAddress = "https://pruebasids.xxxxx.com/.well-known/openid-configuration";
                    options.ClientId = "myWebapp";
                    options.ClientSecret = "myPassword";
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/home/accessdenied";
                    options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/home/index";

                    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                    options.UsePkce = true;
                    options.ResponseMode = OpenIdConnectResponseMode.Query;
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.Scope.Add("myApi.read");

                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                    options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("role", "role", "role");
                    options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
                    options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
                });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }

Please, any help is welcome.
Thanks
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is caused by the certificate which is not trusted from the web application. Try this:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    ...
    // add this lines
    options.BackchannelHttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => true
    };
});
```

**Caution:** In production you should **always** validate the certificate.

Comment: does this just disable the certificate validation?